# Prove that $f$ is not locally bounded on any point of $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Definition :

Assume that $I$ is an interval.
A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is locally bounded on $c \in I$  if there exist $\delta \gt 0 $ and $M \gt 0$ such that :
$\forall x \in I \space\space \space |x-c| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)|\le M$

Question :

Assume that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function defined this way :
If $x$ is not rational, $f(x)=0$.
If $x=\frac{p}{q}$ ( rational ) such that $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ and $q \gt 0$ , then $f(x)=(-1)^pq$.
Prove that $f$ is not locally bounded on any point of $(0,1)$ .

Note :  What should i do ? Is this gonna work if assume that $f$ is locally bounded on an arbitrary point of $(0,1)$ ? Will it reach a contradiction?

Comment: For a detailed proof, you can have a look here [A NOWHERE LOCALLY BOUNDED FUNCTION](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-nowhere-locally-bounded-function/)

Comment: Basically, for large $n$ you want to consider the sequence $\frac 1n \frac 2n ... \frac{n-1}{n}$. For large enough $n$, it's not hard to show that for any $(a,b) \subset I$ some element of that sequence is in $(a,b)$

Comment: Is $f(0.5)=(-1)^12$, or $(-1)^24$?  (I.e., the definition $f(x)=(-1)^pq$ when $x=p/q$ is missing an assumption on $p$ and $q$.)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, your comment gets things a bit backward:  No matter how large you take $n$ to be, the interval $(a,b)=(0,{1\over2n})$ does not contain any element of the sequence.  What you mean is that for all intervals $(a,b)$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n\gt N$ the interval contains an element of the sequence.  (I.e., instead of $\exists n\forall(a,b)$, it should be $\forall(a,b)\exists N\forall n\gt N$...)  Also, you might want to restrict $n$ to be prime; otherwise you have to assert there's an element in the sequence that doesn't reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $x \in (0,1)$, and suppose such $M>0$ exists. There are finitely many $p/q$ such that $q\leq M$ and $p/q \in (0,1)$. Choose an open interval $I$ around $x$ which does not contain any of those. Since the rationals are dense, $I \cap I_\delta$, where $I_{\delta}=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, must have a rational $a/b$ in it for any $\delta$. By construction of $I$, such rational must have $b> M$. Then $|f(a/b)|>M$. Therefore, no $\delta>0$ will do.

As a sidenote, this argument is very similar to the one which proves that the [Thomae's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function) is continuous at the irrationals.

Answer (score 0):

You should assume that $c, \delta, M$ are given, then find the $x$ such that $|f(x)| > M$. In particular, it should be easy to construct an $x$ such that $|f(x)| = p$ where $p$ is a prime larger than $\max(M, 1/\delta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples of not locally bounded functions defined on $\mathbb R$:

1. First one is explicit: [A NOWHERE LOCALLY BOUNDED FUNCTION](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-nowhere-locally-bounded-function/). **This example is almost the one you mention in your original post**.
2. Second one using a Hamel basis (and therefore Axiom of Choice) which on top is linear: [A DISCONTINUOUS MIDPOINT CONVEX FUNCTION](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-discontinuous-midpoint-convex-function/)